# WebGL: Asynchronous texImage2D?

Tags: webgl, angle

I am updating some textures of the scene all the time by new images.
Problem is uploading is synchronous and texImage2D takes ~100ms. It takes so long time even if texture is not used during rendering of the next frame or rendering is switched off.

I am wondering, is there any way to upload texture data asynchronously?

Additional conditions:

I had mention there is old texture which could stay active until uploading of new one to GPU will be finished.

Comment: Try texSubImage2D. If that doesnt cut it maybe rewrite your program so that you dont need a complete new image every frame? I believe the overhead for texture upload is pretty high in webgl.

Comment: Might be of some help: http://toji.github.io/shader-perf/

Comment: Thanks @Abstract Algorithm, interesting technique which will boost my apps.

Comment: Yes @WacławJasper this is solution, more details below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to use texSubImage2D and upload image to GPU by small portions. Once uploading will be finished activate your new texture and delete old one.

Answer (score 4):

> is there any way to upload texture data asynchronously?

no, not in WebGL 1.0. There might be in WebGL 2.0 but that's not out yet.

Somethings you might try.

- make it smaller

  What are you uploading? Video? Can you make it smaller?
- Have you tried different formats?

  WebGL converts from whatever format the image is stored in to the format you request. So for example if you load a .JPG the browser might make an RGB image. If you then upload it with gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE it has to convert the image to RGBA before uploading (more time).
- Do you have UNPACK_FLIP_Y set to true?

  If so WebGL has to flip your image before uploading it.
- Do you have UNPACK_COLORSPACE_CONVERSION_WEBGL set to BROWSER_DEFAULT_WEBGL?

  If not WebGL may have to re-decompress your image
- Do you have UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL set to false or true?

  Depending on how the browser normally stores images it might have 
  to convert the image to the format your requesting
- Images have to be decompressed

  are you sure your time is in "uploading" vs "decompressing"? If you switch to uploading a TypedArray of the same dimensions does it speed up?

Comment: Thank you @gman for quite deep optimization guide, I am going to take into account several advices.

Comment: More discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856403/decode-images-in-web-worker