# How to increase the efficiency of texSubImage2D in webgl?

Tags: javascript, webgl, render

My program is simply showing part of a big picture. Users can move the view port to see different part of the picture. And the picture may be animation, so the program will keep rendering each frame.

It uses texSubImage2D to load the whole picture and renders a part of picture based on the texture loaded, which means if users want to see next picture, the program will load the new picture by texSubImage2D.

Now I want to show two pictures, that is rendering two pictures at the same time, by using the same way.

When user move the view port to the right border of current picutre, the next picture will show and keep the current picture.

What I did is creating a new renderer and use texSubImage2D to load the new picture. Which is working but loading the new picture takes some time so the program lags when running texSubImage2D.

My program is a browser program and uses JS. So there is only one thread and it has to take time to run texSubImage2D.

Is there any method to fix lagging?

Eg. Is it possible only loading a part of the picture so that I can assign loading process to several frames instead of loading whole picture in one frame? It seems that texSubImage2D can only load the whole picture.

This is only one idea I can come up with. There may be other solutions.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58863246/128511) may or may not be related

Comment: I think it's not related. My problem is texSubImage2D has to be ran in the main thread and it costs too much time.