# Speed up, or multi-thread, texture uploading with texImage2D in WebGL

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I'm building a WebGL application that is suffering from a nasty performance bottleneck. The application often needs to burst upload a set of large textures (say 2000 x 2000) to the GPU. Right now it is choking on the `texImage2D` call. Every time I call `texImage2D` there is notable jank. When a burst of them happens, it completely kills the UI experience.

This is actually a port of an OpenGL application. In OpenGL this problem was solved by uploading the texture in a separate thread and that worked very well. As far as I can tell, there is no direct way to do anything similar in WebGL. I initially tried using `OffScreenCanvas` with workers. The plan was to transfer an `OffScreenCanvas` to a `Worker` which would upload the texture, but I found out that I can access the `WebGLRenderingContext` of an `OffScreenCanvas` in only one `Worker`. This defeats my purpose.

Is there any other approach to either speed up the `texImage2D` call, or somehow have the CPU->GPU transfer happen in a separate `Worker`?

There are many different sources I can pass to the `texImage2D` call, can I expect some of them to be more performant than others? `ImageBitmap` seems promising (I'm going to test this), but I can't quite figure out if the data for an `ImageBitmap` is held in the GPU.

Comment: You should try ImageBitmap,that's what it's designed for. Otherwise, I'm pretty sure the answer you want is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856403/decode-images-in-web-worker?rq=1

Comment: I think I made an edit just before you commented about `ImageBitmap`. I'm going to give that a shot. Do you happen to know if `ImageBitmap` data is held in the GPU (for Chrome at least)? From the [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html) I can't quite tell. It seems to suggest that both RAM or GPU is acceptable. Roughly I'm going to: create an OffScreenCanvas in a worker, draw to the 2d context, call createImageBitmap(), transfer it to the main thread, then call texImage2D(). Are there any pitfalls here? E.g. options to createImageBitmap()?

Comment: ImageBitmap is *intended* to hold the data in the GPU but of course it's up to the browser. As an easy data point, if the user doesn't have a GPU ImageBitmap should still function. Transferring from a worker will not really help.

Comment: @gman I had seen your comment on calling  `createImageBitmap()` in a worker in the link you provided. That was informative, I didn't know that `createImageBitmap()` was threaded. I think for my use case I still need the worker because the textures are coming from another (2d) canvas and I need the draw to _that_ to be on a worker thread. I can't see a way to get that data back from the worker thread to the main thread other than to call createImageBitmap() and transfer the result. Do you see any issue with this? I'm not really a graphics person, so I can't evaluate this very confidently.

Comment: sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @gman Thanks! Do you happen to have any recommendations on debugging tools for WebGL? I used to lean on the ability to examine the loaded textures etc in Android and iOS. I can't seem to find anything similar for WebGL on any browser. spectorjs is what I am using now.

Comment: Try Spector it’s great for inspecting frames

Comment: Thanks @pailhead. Unfortunately, I was not able to solve the performance issue, so I abandoned the project. I'll keep it in mind for any future WebGL work.